# configure pip, give it python interpreter

Tags: python, pip

I am new to python. I have installed pip and it have `python2.4` interpreter,

I want to give  pip newer version of python interpreter.

how can I do that on `Unix system?`

I am trying this:

```
pip --environment=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/
```

but it not works.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have Python 2.6 installed? If so, install pip for that version of Python and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to `pip` you can also run `pip2.x` and `pip3.y` (for python2.x and 3.y respectively)

Comment: tried this: pip2.6 install sqlalchemy 

but it gives error: -bash: pip2.6: command not found

Comment: @irakli2692 try doing `ls /usr/bin/pip*` and see if you have `pip2.6` binary. If not you'll have to install it